# Django: how to trigger creation of ContentTypes for new models?

Tags: django

At what point are new ContentTypes created, and how can I trigger this myself?

I have a bunch of migrations, creating new models and such. After that's all done there is a final data migration that assigns the permissions for these new objects to any groups that already have related permissions. (Hereby 'Related permissions' are chosen by me to make sense within the application)

However, the ContentTypes for the newly created models are not available yet when I run that datamigration. They are when I run all other migrations first, and only then run the extra datamigration. I.e. run the command twice. But making that manual patch is not feasable scenario in my case.

So I'd like to manually trigger the creation of ContentTypes for any new models right before I run my datamigration. How is this done?

Comment: How are you getting your ContentTypes? [get_for_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentTypeManager.get_for_model) would normally work.

Comment: for ct in orm['contenttypes.contenttype'].objects.filter(app_label='client')

But I guess I could simply be explicit about it; good suggestion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [`ContentType.objects.get_for_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentTypeManager.get_for_model), which creates the `ContentType` instances on demand (it adds some caching as well).

Comment: This has the drawback of not being able to write the general case ("all content types for app so-and-so") but it does help me fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: The question states "After that's all done there is a final data migration that assigns the permissions for these new objects to any groups that already have related permissions." `ContentType.objects.get_for_model()` does not create any Permission models.